# Пропадает скрипт при выборе popup после редактированния Editor скриптом

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

После редактировании Editor-а скриптом, пропадает сам скрипт при выборе в popup. Как исправить?
Все видно в коде и на скриншотах.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Cards))]
public class CardsMod : Editor
{
    string[] costTypes = { "action", "mana" };
    int costIndex;
    string[] spellTypes = { "Creature", "Spell" };
    int spellIndex;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();
        EditorGUILayout.Space(10);

        Cards cards = (Cards)target;

        #region Настойка стоимости карты
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        cards.GetCost = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Стоимость карты", cards.GetCost);

        costIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup(costIndex, costTypes);
        if (costIndex == 0)
            cards.GetCostType = costTypes[0];
        else
            cards.GetCostType = costTypes[1];

        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        #endregion

        #region Выбор типа карты
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField(new GUIContent("Тип карты", "Призыв или заклинание"));

        spellIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup(spellIndex, spellTypes);
        if (spellIndex == 0)
        {
            cards.GetIsCreature = true;
            cards.GetCreature = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(cards.GetCreature, typeof(GameObject), true) as GameObject;
        }
        else
        {
            cards.GetIsCreature = false;
            cards.GetBonus.name = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Spell name");
        }
        
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        #endregion

        if (GUILayout.Button("Play card"))
        {
            cards.GetActive = true;
            Debug.Log(cards.GetActive);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Так скрипт выглядит в редакторе]
[image: Так выглядит после смены "Тип карты"]

Я что-то читал, что могут быть какие-то проблемы при использовании EditorGUILayout и GUILayout одновременно. Но что если мне нужен popup, например, которого нет в GUILayout? :(

Answer (score 0):

Что ж, что бы справится с этим мне пришлось просто добавлять еще одну строчку, тогда все работает fine. А так же все `EditorGUILayout.Begin(end)Horizontal();` заменил на `GUILayout.Begin(end)Horizontal();`:

```
#region Выбор типа карты
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        GUILayout.Label(new GUIContent("Тип карты", "Призыв или заклинание"));

        spellIndex = GUILayout.SelectionGrid(spellIndex, spellTypes, spellTypes.Count());
        
        
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        if (spellIndex == 0)
        {
            cards.GetIsCreature = true;
            creature = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(cards.GetCreature, typeof(GameObject), true) as GameObject;
            cards.GetCreature = creature;
        }
        else
        {
            cards.GetIsCreature = false;
            cards.GetBonusName = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Название заклинания", bonusName);
        }

        #endregion
```